# R function for finding mean of a population greater than a specific value

Tags: r, for-loop, random, mean, sample

!°[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB0bh.jpg)

I’m currently learning R and I’ve hit a rock. How do I present the code for the proportion of the population taller than 15m. (Question 5 in the picture)

[image: number 5 question in this attachment- for a randomly generated sample in a dataset]

Tried using a for loop but can figure out what to input for the vector.
I’m expecting a cut-of for values from 15m and above

```
d<- read.csv('Eucalyptus1_.csv')

str(d)
hight <- (d$hgt)
sample(hight, size = 5)
sample1<-sample(hight, size = 5)
mean(sample1)
median(sample1)
sd(sample1)
quantile(sample1)
```

This is the line I’m struggling with -

```
for (sample1 > 15 in vector) { 
  
}
```

Comment: Please show your earnest attempt at the problem. See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/1422451)

Comment: Please provide example code :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example Helpful

Answer (score 0):

##### Vectorisation

It is important to understand the vectorised nature of R and that you will almost never need a `for` loop.

What is a vector? For example, the column `hgt` in your data is essentially a vector. A variable named `hgt` containing multiple values.

lets recreate an example vector (a variable named x containig multiple values)

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Many operations in R are vectorised. This means, they are carried out on each element of the vector simultaneously and there is no need to go through each element one at a time.

Here is an example:

```
x + 1
# 2 3 4 5 6
```

As a result, we get another vector, where the operation `+ 1` was carried out on each element of the original vector.

Therefore, you will not need a `for` loop.

Just replace the `+ 1` operation with the appropriate operation for your problem.

What you are looking for is:

- to check whether each element in `hgt` meets a certain condition, for example `> 15`

The operation "condition check" is done in R via logical operators such as `>` `==` or `<` or `<=` or `>=` or `!=` .

Lets find out the values in x that are `> 3`.

```
x > 3
# FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

What we get is yet another vector that contains the result of the condition check for each element of `x`.

Now there is one other concept that is missing. How to extract certain values from a vector.

This is done via the index operator `[ ]`.
For example, if I wanted to extract values that are bigger than 3, I would write `x[x > 3]`. Read this in your mind as "Give me the values of x where x is bigger than 3".

##### Sampling Distribution

I want to point out that you are missing an important step that your teacher is wanting you to do. It is to repeat the sampling process + calculation of the demanded statistic for each sample 1000 times, in order to get to a sampling distribution [check this out for a real life hands on example why this should even be important](https://moderndive.com/7-sampling.html).

(Remember that I told you to *almost never* use a `for` loop. Maybe it is appropriate to use one to run the same function 1000 times.)

Comment: Thanks @uke. This provided a great insight that I needed. 
Each sample contains 5 values (n=5) and I need (n=5) 1000 times but going with the example in the link you attached, it just replicated same value 1000 times (1000 x5). I used the function rep(sample(d$hgt, size = 5), 1000). So how do I generate 1000 different samples of an experiment with n=5 observation per experiment?

Comment: This is because `rep()` does not really evaluate its content 1000 times. As you pointed out, it rather calculates the content once and repeats the result 1000 times. 
A readymade function for repeating sampling n times is `moderndive::rep_sample_n()`. But I guess your teacher wants you to write your own approach, so I would suggest to go with a `for`-loop.